# DB for portable and server usage

Tags: database, deployment

I am going to develop a new C# Application that uses a database. The DB has to fit the following needs:

- If the app can connect to the company's DB then it will be in edit mode and use that DB
- If not it will be in read-only mode. Then I want to use a local DB that will be synchronized with the company's DB regularly. Then the use can be offline.
- I would like the app to run without installation. Just copy the files and go.

That is why I thought about SQLite. I is just a file that can be copied. But the problem is that I can't use SQLite on a server with multiple users, right?

**I need a DB that can be accessed by multipe users and does not have to be installed.**

Which DB would fit my needs best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL server compact which requires no installation. It also supports multiple users and replication which seems to cover the needs you outlined.